# How to navigate back to previous page without reloading it when dynamically loading the pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am facing some issues with navigation back to previous page(dynamically loading the pages). What I am trying to do is in a back-button click I am navigating to previous page; which is working fine. The problem is that the previous page is reloading every time on navigating back.

I also used navController.pop(),navController.navigateBack("previouspage/");but getting same issue.

Can someone help me figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

It is normal behavior. When you navigate to another page Angular by default creates a new `Component` for page any time. If you need to reuse exists page `Component`, you must implement your own `RouterReuseStrategy`. Read about it in the official documentation (https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy) or on medium (https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/angular-route-reuse-strategy-b5d40adce841).